# Is the Lorenz system well-posed in the Hadamard sense?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, chaos-theory, stability-theory

Apologies if this has already been discussed, but I searched the site and I couldn't find an answer.

For the sake of simplicity, consider only ODEs, possibly depending on some vector of parameters $\mathbf{p}$. The definition of a well-posed problem in the Hadamard sense is:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-posed_problem

The third point says that "the solution's behavior changes continuously with the initial conditions". I'm not sure what's the rigorous meaning of this. I interpret it as "the integral operator which associates the forcing term, the parameters and the initial condition(s) to the solution of the ODE is continuous", which seems to agree with the usual interpretation that "small changes in the data lead to small changes in the solution".

*However*, the Lorenz system is usually considered ill-posed: see

https://ac.els-cdn.com/089812219400188X/1-s2.0-089812219400188X-main.pdf?_tid=27b719d7-543e-4290-bfe6-e9d62887ba6c&acdnat=1549797064_ba8fd399224e0c3170aef5cc8ba4a182

Doesn't the solution depend continuously on data, though? Sure, changes $\epsilon$ in the initial conditions or in $\mathbf{p}$ will cause changes of order $\epsilon\exp(\lambda t)$ in time $t$, which may be exponentially large, but they still depend continuously on $\epsilon$, don't they? So, why would it be ill-posed?

Also more recent paper *seem* to consider the Lorenz system ill-posed, though admittedly it's not stated explicitly:

https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/85e5/908a9e21fb1c017c4206cf4df4475c89bdd8.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\mathbf{p}_n$ be a sequence of parameter values that converges to $\mathbf{p}$, and let $X_n$ and $X$ the solutions corresponding to those parameters. For a fixed time $T>0$, the solutions $X_n$ converge uniformly to $X$ on $[0,T]$. On $[0,\infty)$, the convergence will be pointwise but not uniform. You can then say that the problem is well posed on finite intervals, but non on $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: Thanks. I always consider finite intervals (this is for applications) thus the problem is for all practical purposes well-posed. Good to know!

Comment: PS this holds also if the change is not In the Lorenz system parameters ($\rho, \sigma$ and $\beta$ as defined here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorenz_system but on the initial data, right?

Comment: Yes. You can always transform initial data int parameters and vice versa.